# 'execute unless entity @a[x_rotation=-180.0,y_rotation=0.9]' will always run even if entities rotation values are equal to the ones specified

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, technical-issues

I need the player always to be facing a certain direction but I can't use a repeating command block to teleport you to the same place every tick. I tried this command: `execute unless entity @a[x_rotation=-179.0,y_rotation=0.9]` but even when your x and y rotation is -180.0 and 0.9 is still runs the command. Why is this?

Thanks,
Dream

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if @a checks all entities, wouldn't it mean that **all** entities (all players, enemies, some blocks even) have to be facing that direction? And if they don't, it executes

Comment: I just had a check and here: https://gist.github.com/Dinnerbone/3736487 , it says: "@a a list of all players". I don't think it has anything to do with entites. If @a targeted entities as well, when I run a tp command, all entites should teleport but they dont.

Comment: Is there more than one player that can be targeted right now? (i.e. are there other players on the server?)  `execute unless` will only run the chained command if the result of the test (in this case, the number of entities found) returns exactly 0.  It would help a bit if you also included which command you wanted to run with this execute.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It turns out that that it should be: `execute unless entity @a[x_rotation=0.9,y_rotation=-179.0]` since the x and y are flipped compared to the co-ords. It should also be something like: `execute unless entity @a[x_rotation=-0.5..0.9,y_rotation=175.0..181.0]` so it targets players between certain values rather than specific ones. If you imagine something rotating on the y-axis it would be theoretically be spinning left to right or right to left and on the x-axis it would be spinning up and down.